# How to create the movement in Snake Game?

Tags: java

I am trying to make the classic snake game that eats the apple but I am having problems with the movements. The snake is able to move diagonal. For example, when the snake is moving to the right and I click up arrow key it will go diagonal not straight up y coordinate. How can I fix this problem? Thank you.

Game.java

```
public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable, KeyListener {

public static int width = 300;
public static int height = width / 16 * 9;
public static int scale = 3;

private Thread thread;
private JFrame frame;
private Snake snake;
private boolean running = false;


public Game(){
    Dimension size = new Dimension(width * scale, height * scale);
    setPreferredSize(size);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    addKeyListener(this);

    frame = new JFrame();
    snake = new Snake(200, 200);
}

public synchronized void start(){
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this, "Display");
    thread.start();
}

public synchronized void stop(){
    running = false;
    try{
        thread.join();
    }catch (InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void run(){
    while (running){
        update();
        render();
    }
}

public void update(){

}

public void render(){
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null){
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        snake.draw(g);

        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W)  {
        snake.setYD(-1);
    }

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S){
        snake.setYD(1);
    }


    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A){
        snake.setXD(-1);
    }

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D){
        snake.setXD(1);
    }

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public static void main (String[] args){
    Game game = new Game(); 

    game.frame.setResizable(false);
    game.frame.setTitle("Snake");
    game.frame.add(game);
    game.frame.pack();
    game.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    game.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    game.frame.setVisible(true);

    game.start();
}
}
```

Entity.java

```
public abstract class Entity {

protected int x, y;

public Entity(int x, int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public void draw(Graphics g){
}

public int getX() {return x;}
public int getY() {return y;}

}
```

Snake.java

```
public class Snake extends Entity {

private int xDirection, yDirection;

public Snake(int x, int y) {
    super(x, y);
}

public void draw(Graphics g){
    move();

    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillRect(x, y, 15, 15);
}

public void move(){
    x += xDirection;
    y += yDirection;
}



public void setXD(int value){
    xDirection = value;
}

public void setYD(int value){
    yDirection = value;
}
```

Comment: You need to implement some "exclusivity" logic that only allows one direction to be moved in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the snake from moving on the other axis. This should do the trick.

```
if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W)  {
    snake.setYD(-1);
    snake.setXD(0);
}

if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S){
    snake.setYD(1);
    snake.setXD(0);
}


if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A){
    snake.setXD(-1);
    snake.setYD(0);
}

if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D){
    snake.setXD(1);
    snake.setYD(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You set the coordinates to 1 and -1, but you never set it to 0. So if you once set y to 1 then you set x to 1, then it will be a diagonal movement (1,1). You should set y to zero when you set x to 1 or -1, if you do not want to move diagonal.

So

```
if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W)  {
    snake.setYD(-1);
    snake.setXD(0);
}
```

After this you can only move straight. (May be it is not the most beautiful solution but this is the answer your question)